# Simulate Pairs (X, Y) from a Common Distribution?

Tags: r, simulation, distribution

I wanted to use R to simulate pairs from a common distribution, and just wanted to check if my approach is correct:

X, Y ~ N(15, 4) (independently and identically distributed)

So, if I wanted to simulate 10 (x, y) pairs from this normal distribution, would I just do:

```
x <- rnorm(10, 15, 4)
y <- rnorm(10, 15, 4)
```

And then the these two vectors would contain 10 samples each and we could consider corresponding elements pairs? Or is there a different way to simulate the two variables at the same time/step?

Comment: This question is probably better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  The central question seems more conceptual than syntactic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not supposed to be drawing actual pairs from a 2D multivariate normal, then yes, you're drawing IID samples and making couplings from `x` and `y` gives you "pairs".  It's kind of a strange way to think about pairs though.

You could just as easily do `matrix(rnorm(20, 15, 4), nrow = 2)`.  Given that the draws in `rnorm` are independent, you don't actually need two separate calls to `rnorm`.